# @RequestBody is not mapping to the Bean in my Post RestAPI

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Post method in my restApi in which i am mapping JSON to the Bean using @RequestBody. here is my code for the controller where i map my JSON to Employee bean

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        super();
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    
    //build restAPi for create Employee
    
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee),HttpStatus.CREATED );
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Below is the Employee bean class

```
@Data
@Entity //makes this as JPA entity
@Table(name="employee")  // if not defined it creates the table with class name by default
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email_id")
    private String emailId;

}
```

Also, this is my Service class

```
@Override
public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

the JSON request i post to this service is as follows

```
{
    "firstName" : "Priya",
    "lastName" : "Venkatesan",
    "emailId" : "priyavenkat@gmail.com"
}
```

I am not sure what i am missing and i am new for API development. Please request help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea about the issue :
You are using lombok in your jpa entity. You might have a problem with Lombok and your getters/setters are not generated, which make it impossible to map your json & your Employee object.

Comment: Thnak you. after using getter and setter the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to use persistence entity in @RequestBody of the controller.

Please check out this link: [Should entity class be used as request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639251/should-entity-class-be-used-as-request-body)